# Automatically generated Entities from mysql database in Netbeans always fail to deploy

Tags: mysql, jpa-2.0, netbeans-7

I am new to Java EE (and to Netbeans). I have am trying to automatically generate entity classes from my mysql database... For simple relationships it works, but for the following it always fails:

[image]

i get the following error:

> Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field tblExpandituresTranx] from the entity class [class entities.restaurant.TblContents] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.. Please see server.log for more details.

I think... I have some error in my database or perhaps EclipseLink JPA tool is kaput! 
please help!

Comment: haha... that was prompt.. hang on, I'll correct it!

Comment: would really appreciate if someone came up with an solution for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself...
Apparently JPA has a problem with multiple primary keys in bridge tables. So, instead of having foreign keys as primaries I just converted them to unique indexed and everything worked just fine!! wuhu!!

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your schema is upside down.

Or you could actually read the exception you're getting and figure out what it's telling you:

```
The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field tblExpandituresTranx] from the entity class [class entities.restaurant.TblContents] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn
```

Looks like you've got an incomplete specification for the JOIN.

Comment: but I am not doing anything by myself... it is being automatically generated by Netbeans

Comment: That's the problem - you're letting NetBeans do too many things that you don't understand at all.  It's a bad idea when you're unfamiliar with a technology to let things happen behind the scenes without some knowledge.

Comment: That is it, you are right! but I am trying to learn, but the problem is... could you please help me resolve this one... I am going to learn loads doing it! and I'd really appreciate it!